# How do I prevent a gVim server window stealing focus when receiving a remote command?

Tags: gvim, window-management

I'm writing a debugger and when hitting a breakpoint or stepping through code I'm making a system call that instructs a gVim server to jump to the current line of the file being debugged, like this:

```
system_call("gvim --remote-send +\"%dG" --servername DEBUG --remote-tab-silent %s",
             line_number, file_name);
```

The problem is each time gVim receives the command the gVim window steals focus and I have to alt-tab or mouse-click back to the debugger window.

**How can I prevent the gVim server window stealing focus when it receives at command?**

(I've tagged the question with `microsoft-windows` and `linux` as I alternate between both operating systems and as such an answer would ideally work on both.)

Comment: Are you looking for `:help -f`?

Comment: @romainl I added `-f` to the call to gVim and it made no difference; it sill steals focus on every call. What were you thinking it would do?

Comment: @x-x did you ever solve this? interestingly i have the opposite problem: i cannot make gvim get focus with `remote_foreground()`

Comment: @JackeJR No, I never solved it.

Answer (score 1):

A solution to this problem is mentioned in Vim's documentation (`:h --remote`). The following command should open *filename* to *line_number*:

```bash
gvim --servername DEBUG --remote-send "<C-\><C-N>:tab drop filename<CR>line_numberG"
```

Note that this seems to neither raise nor focus Vim. And I believe that opening the file using `:tab drop filename` should work similar to `vim --remote-tab-silent filename`. Also, note that I tested this using the `i3` and `awesome` window managers.

```
:h --remote    --remote [+{cmd}] {file} ...                                 *--remote*
                                Open the file list in a remote Vim.  When
                                there is no Vim server, execute locally.
                                There is one optional init command: +{cmd}.
                                This must be an Ex command that can be
                                followed by "|". 
                                The rest of the command line is taken as the
                                file list.  Thus any non-file arguments must
                                come before this.
                                You cannot edit stdin this way |--|.
                                The remote Vim is raised.  If you don't want
                                this use
                                 vim --remote-send "<C-\><C-N>:n filename<CR>"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux, here is a bit of a hacky solution. You can augment your `gvim` command with a shell command that interacts with windows, like `xdotool` or `wmctrl`. Here's an example using `xdotool`:

```bash
xdotool getactivewindow > /tmp/gvim_wid.txt && \
gvim --servername DEBUG --remote-tab-silent +line_number file_name && \
gvim --servername DEBUG --remote-expr "system('cat /tmp/gvim_wid.txt | xargs xdotool windowactivate')"
```

Explanation:

- *line 1*: use `xdotool` to get the window ID of the debugger window, and save it to a file (`/tmp/gvim_wid.txt`)
- *line 2*: run your `gvim` command
- *line 3*: run another `gvim` command which executes an `xdotool` command to focus the debugger window (using the window ID from the file)

A similar approach would be to save the window ID to a shell variable instead of a file, and run the final `xdotool` command directly from the shell. However, I was only able to make that method work by adding a `sleep` command before the final `xdotool` command.

Also, I don't know if there is an `xdotool` alternative in Windows, but I imagine there must be something similar.